We were unable to review the app because it crashed on launch
our app gets rejected as it crashes on launch.  According to the logs, it happens because the app attempts to access private-sensitive data. We don't collect any of personal data, so it is probably done by Google Firebase embedded in the app (Core, Firestore, Auth). Maybe you have met similar cases and know any of Firebase settings that disable attempts of accessing privacy-sensitive data? We already set FirebaseDataCollectionDefaultEnabled to NO in info.plist, but it still not enough. Maybe error in facebook sdk? Before that it was written that there was an error when starting the ipad air 5
Log1
Log2
Log3
Try to write in apple file that we don't collect any private data and ask user to allow transparency tracking - still not working

The crash says that your app tried to access user tracking data. I would be looking at advertising frameworks and ensure that you have configured all of the requirements for app tracking transparency.

@Paulw11 we have facebook sdk. How to turn off trying access user traking data from him? We developing on unity
